# Modificación del modelo

Tags: django

Modifiqué mi modelo, pero ahora cuando realizo el `manage.py migrate` éste me arroja un error diciendo que no existen unos campos.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Empleados(models.Model):

    OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
    )

    OPCIONES_ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES = (
        ('C', 'Casado'),
        ('S', 'Soltero'),
        ('V', 'Viudo')
    )

    OPCIONES_GRADO_INSTRUCCION_CHOICES = (
        ('B', 'Bachiller'),
        ('U', 'Universitaria'),
        ('T', 'Tecnico superior')
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
        upload_to="archivo/",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    ) 
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    grado_instruccion = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GRADO_INSTRUCCION_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_de_hijos = models.IntegerField()
    fecha_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

Y este es lo que me muestra por terminal:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la columna datos_empleados.direccion
>   LINE 1: ...eados"."telefono", "datos_empleados"."documento", "datos_emp...
>                                                                ^
>
> [04/Sep/2018 17:22:48] "GET /registrar/listado HTTP/1.1" 500 202275.

He revisado y no me logro ver cual es el error.

Comment: Hiciste primero el `manage.py makemigrations`?

Answer (score 0):

ya pude resolver la situación, el problema era la base de datos, debido a que esta tenia información. La solución consistió en eliminar la base de datos y crear una nueva en el setting, posterior a esto se realiza el makemigrate, y luego el migrate, y listo, se crea la tabla en la base de datos con todos los campos.

Comment: No es necesario eliminar la base de datos si no imaginate que seria si tuvieras un monton de datos. Para cuando arroja ese tipo de errores simplemente es remplazar esos valores que aun no tenia tu modelo por valores por default que lo hace django muy rapido

Comment: Es verdad pero en este caso como no tenia datos de importancia con eliminar la base se hace mas simple, pero lo que dices es verdad, otra opción es copiar la base de datos y luego de la modificación realizar la migración desde la copia.